# Targeting ES6 in tsconfig.json fixes cannot find name

Tags: json, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am going through a tutorial on AngularJS. The code can be found at https://github.com/planetoftheweb/learnangular/tree/02_01e 
I am using exactly this code. When I run npm start, I get this error:

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(39,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(21,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(31,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(40,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(42,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(35,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(36,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(106,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(122,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(148,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(47,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(353,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(354,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(355,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(356,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(357,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(358,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(359,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(360,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(360,97): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(361,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(362,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(363,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(364,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(365,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(365,117): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(366,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(368,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(369,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(370,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(371,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(434,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(459,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(467,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(468,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(470,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(471,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(475,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(477,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(693,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(694,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(710,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(711,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(826,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(841,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(845,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(845,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(856,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1479,36): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1483,43): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1487,50): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1491,40): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1495,38): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1499,37): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1503,39): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1507,38): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1511,39): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1515,37): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1519,43): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1523,43): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1527,43): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2294,36): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2298,43): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2302,50): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2306,40): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2310,38): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2314,37): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2318,39): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2322,38): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2326,39): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2330,37): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2334,43): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2338,43): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2342,43): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! learn-angular@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-angular@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/craigbertrand/.npm/_logs/2017-11-06T15_09_02_610Z-debug.log
```

Running `npm -v` logs 5.5.1

If I change the target in `tsconfig.json` form es5 to es6, everything works. 
I've read in other places, however, that targeting es5 is basically standard and if you target es6 then you're in danger of not supporting older browsers. Is this still true? If it *is* bad practice, what is a better solution?

Comment: ES6 is not supported by most of the browsers yet like IE , if you are targeting ES6 then you need a transpiler like babel or traceur js to transpile the code so that browser can understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/planetoftheweb/learnangular/issues/13) for exactly this on the GitHub repository. One of the comments on there gives a solution that appears to have worked for a few people:

> ...solved it by adding this line to my tsconfig.json file
>   `"lib" : ["es2015", "es2015.iterable", "dom"]`

As you suggested, targetting ES5 gives better browser support. Once you target ES6, you will require a browser that supports ES6, which may or not be a problem depending on your audience. Personally, I would target ES5 for the higher compatibility.